# How to pass a file as a graphql variable?

Tags: file-upload, graphql

How do I pass a file upload as a graphql mutation variable? Submitting this test gives me a 400 bad request with this error:

```
Variable \"$thumbnailFile\" got invalid value {}; Upload value invalid.
```

I am using graphql-upload. I am sending my queries like this:

```
async function graphQLFetch(query, variables = {}){
    const response = await fetch('/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables })
    });
    const body = await response.text();
    const result = JSON.parse(body);
    return result.data;
}
```

In my react component:

```
handleThumbnailChange(event){
    const thumbnailFile = event.target.files[0];
    const query = `mutation addThumbnailTest($thumbnailFile: Upload){
        addThumbnailTest(thumbnailFile: $thumbnailFile){
            thumbnailSrc
        }
    }`;
    const data = await graphQLFetch(query, {
        thumbnailFile
    });
}
```

My schema:

```
scalar Upload

type Mutation {
    addThumbnailTest(thumbnailFile: Upload): String
}
```

My server is setup like the following:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { GraphQLUpload, graphqlUploadExpress } = require('graphql-upload');
const express = require('express');

const resolvers = {
    Upload: GraphQLUpload,
    Mutation: {
        handleThumbnailChange: handleThumbnailChange,
    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'), 'utf-8'),
    resolvers
});

async function installHandler(app){
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
}

const app = express();

(async function start(){
    try{
        // Install GraphQL API Handler
        app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
        await installHandler(app);
```

Comment: You haven't specified what the `Upload` type is or what server you're using, so this is tough to answer.

Comment: Upload is provided by GraphQLUpload

Comment: bad request ... https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Answer (score 1):

I had to submit the query as form data and without the `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` header

```
async function graphQLFetch(query, variables = {}, multipart = false){
    let request;
    if(multipart){
        const data = {
            operations: JSON.stringify({
                query,
                variables: {
                    ...variables,
                    file: null
                }
            }),
            map: JSON.stringify({
                '0': [
                    'variables.file'
                ]
            })
        };
        const requestBody = new FormData();
        for(const name in data) {
            requestBody.append(name, data[name]);
        }
        requestBody.append('0', variables.file);
        request = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: requestBody
        }
    } else {
        request = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables })
        }
    }
    const response = await fetch('/graphql', request);
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    const result = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    return result.data;
}
```